# how to display multiple input array values in table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a problem with displaying data in table format. i have a multiple input elements like this

```
<form id="purchaseform" class="cv-form" method="post" action="requestmail.php" name="purchaseform" >
        <input name="item_name[]" type="text" value="" id="item_name" class="input_text" />
    <input name="item_brand[]" type="text" value="" id="item_brand" class="input_text"/>
    <input name="model_number[]" type="text" value="" id="model_number" class="input_text"/>
    <input  name="item_website_catalogue[]" type="text" id="item_website_catalogue" value="" class="input_text"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

when i submit this form the post data is like this

```
[item_name] => Array ( 
    [0] => item1 
    [1] => item2 
) 
[item_brand] => Array ( 
    [0] => brand1 
    [1] => brand2 
) 
[model_number] => Array ( 
    [0] => model1 
    [1] => model2 
) 
[item_website_catalogue] => Array ( 
    [0] => source1 
    [1] => source2 
)
```

Here i am not inserting into Database. These will go to Email. i need to these data display in table format like this

### **Item Id** **Itemname**  **Itembrand**  **Itemmodel**

1  -----------testitem------------testbrand-------testmodel

2  -----------testitem2------------testbrand2-------testmodel2

please help me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<count($array['item_name']);$i++) {
    $rows[$i]['item_name'] = $array['item_name'][$i];
    $rows[$i]['item_brand'] = $array['item_brand'][$i];
    $rows[$i]['model_number'] = $array['model_number'][$i];
}
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Item Id</th>
        <th>Itemname</th>
        <th>Itembrand</th>
        <th>Itemmodel</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $i=1;
    foreach($rows as $row) { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['item_brand'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['model_number'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $i++;
    } 
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, just try `for loop`: 
here is an example to create your `html` and then you can send `$output` inside the email

```
<?php
$item_nameArr = $_REQUEST['item_name']  =  array ( 0 => 'item1', 1 => 'item2' );
$item_brandArr = $_REQUEST['item_brand'] = array ( 0 => 'brand1', 1 => 'brand2' ) ;
$model_numberArr = $_REQUEST['model_number'] = array ( 0 => 'model1', 1 => 'model2' ) ;
$item_website_catalogueArr = $_REQUEST['item_website_catalogue'] = array ( 0 => 'source1', 1 => 'source2' ) ;

$count = count($item_nameArr);
$output = '<table>';
$output .= '<tr>';
    $output .= '<td>Count</td>';
    $output .= '<td>Item name</td>';
    $output .= '<td>Item brand</td>';
    $output .= '<td>Item model</td>';
    $output .= '<td>Item catalogue</td>';
$output .= '</tr>';

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $output .= '<tr>';
        $output .= '<td>'.($i+1).'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$item_nameArr[$i].'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$item_brandArr[$i].'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$model_numberArr[$i].'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$item_website_catalogueArr[$i].'</td>';
    $output .= '</tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `<table>` HTML element.
But if you don't want to or can't use it, you can use `str_pad` function.

Suppose you have the array from the post

```
$post_data = [item_name] => Array ( 
    [0] => item1 
    [1] => item2 
) 
[item_brand] => Array ( 
    [0] => brand1 
    [1] => brand2 
) 
[model_number] => Array ( 
    [0] => model1 
    [1] => model2 
) 
[item_website_catalogue] => Array ( 
    [0] => source1 
    [1] => source2 
)
```

1. Find the longest string in your array:

   ```
   $len = 0;
   foreach ($post_data as $v) {
       foreach($v as $value) {
           $len = max($len, strlen($value));
       }
   }
   ```

2. Prepare rows for e-mail contents.

```
     $rows = array();
        foreach ($post_data as $v) {
            $row= array();
            foreach($v as $value) {
                $row[] = '-----------'.str_pad($value, $len+10, '-', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
            }
            $rows[] = implode('', $row);
        }
        //$email_text = implode("\r\n", $rows);
```